# nHibernate: SessionFactory.Evict(type) not working as expected

Tags: nhibernate

```
<syscache>
<cache region="MyCacheRegion" expiration="600" priority="1" />
```

This works as expected. but  SessionFactory.Evict(type) not working as expected.
So after 10 minutes cache ( 2nd level) is cleared but if I need to clear cache when needed I before that I am not able to do it.
What can be the reason? Is there a way to programmatically achieve what is mention in syscahe config?